# how to add hidden value in joint JS so that the value can be shown when the element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

im confused why this doesnt work... first i make this function:

```
var member = function (x, y, rank, name, img, background, textColor, proyek) {

    textColor = textColor || "#000";

    var cell = new joint.shapes.org.Member({
        position: { x: x, y: y },
        attrs: {
            '.card': { fill: "#fff", stroke: background },
            image: {},           
            '.rank': { text: rank, fill: textColor, 'word-spacing': '3px', 'letter-spacing': 0 },
            '.name': { text: name, fill: textColor, 'font-size': 11, 'font-family': 'Calibri', 'letter-spacing': 0, 'text-align': 'left' },
            mycustom: proyek
        }
    });

    graph.addCell(cell);
    return cell;
};
```

then the function called in this code... with the adding of parameter value i get from the loop

```
  var strname = member(positionx2, 200, 'Proyek ' + name + ' (' + dataLevel[i].Total + ') ', '', '#7c68fd', '#000000', dataLevel[i].Proyek);
```

then i make the value shown on alert by this code...

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdown',
    function (cellView, evt, x, y) {
    //    alert('cell view ' + cellView.model.attr('mycustom') + ' was clicked');
    }
);
```

mycustom always undefined.. but if i change  mycustom: proyek to  mycustom: 'foo'  its works.. why is this happening?

can anybody help me.. thanks